# Only rewrite when domain only

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to only write the domain then the domian itself it requested and not to rewrite when there are any subdirectories.

So when accessing

```
example.com
```

you sent to

```
example.com/fr
```

but when you go to

```
example.com/albums
```

you get taken to

```
example.com/albums
```

not

```
example.com/fr/albums
```

which is what is happening with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.fr/fr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're capturing the URI in the RewriteRule with `(.*)` and appending it to the end in your substitution with `$1`. You need to only match on the domain and remove both of those.

Try this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/fr [L,R=301,NC]
```